# awk: add an autoincrement field to a file

Tags: awk

I have the following problem, given a file

```
val1 val2 text_0 
val1 val2 text_0 
val1 val2 text_0 
...
val1 val2 text_1 
val1 val2 text_1 
val1 val2 text_1 
...
val1 val2 text_2 
val1 val2 text_2 
val1 val2 text_2 
...
```

I need to append an auto increment on each `text_` column, such that the auto increments start from 0 on every new token, e.g.

```
val1 val2 text_0_0 
val1 val2 text_0_1 
val1 val2 text_0_2 
...
val1 val2 text_1_0 
val1 val2 text_1_1 
val1 val2 text_1_2 
...
```

I'm not proficient with AWK, I could not find a way to do this.

Answer (score 7):

Short ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '{ $3=$3"_"a[$3]++ }1' file
```

The approximate output:

```
val1 val2 text_0_0
val1 val2 text_0_1
val1 val2 text_0_2
...  
val1 val2 text_1_0
val1 val2 text_1_1
val1 val2 text_1_2
...  
val1 val2 text_2_0
val1 val2 text_2_1
val1 val2 text_2_2
```

---

- `a[$3]++` - count the 3rd field value occurrence via post-increment (`<var>++`)